# ggplot2 panel populates with the wrong values when inside for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a scatterplot matrix using nested for loops, ggplot2 and grid.arrange. The loops iterate over the columns to create the different subplots. This obviously works, because the subplot labs are different for each plot. The plot axis and panel are the same for every subplot though. Now it gets interesting: The columns used are the case i = j = 4, which is even in a different branch of the if-else.

My first try was to force a deep copy with rlang's duplicate() function.
The only other hint I found was to explicitely use print() to display the plot. see:
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f
Neither option changed anything in the final plot.
Removing the if-else stuff to always generate the i<j branch produces the "same" plot. Creating the 16 plots manually (hardcoded, without loops) produces the desired behaviour.

Code example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(egg)

#species is in last column
n = ncol(iris) - 1
plot_list = list()

for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:n) {
    #diagonal
    if (i==j) {
      new_plot = ggplot() + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, size = 5, label = colnames(iris)[i]) + theme_void()
    }
    #upper triangle
    else if (i < j) {
      #assign to new plot nested into a print(), doesn't help
      new_plot = print(
        ggplot() +
        geom_point(aes(x = iris[,j], y = iris[,i], colour=iris[,5]), shape=18, size=3.5) +
        labs(x = colnames(iris)[j], y = colnames(iris)[i]) +
        theme_light() +
        theme(legend.position="none")
      )
    }
    #lower triangle
    else {
      new_plot = ggplot() + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, size = 5, label = "lower triangle") + theme_void()
    }

    #this doesn't help
    print(new_plot)
    #this doesn't help either
    plot_buffer = duplicate(new_plot, shallow=FALSE)
    #append new plot to plot list
    plot_list = append(plot_list, list(plot_buffer))
  }
}

grid.arrange(grobs = plot_list, top = "grand title")
```

Here's the faulty plot. Petal.Width is used as x and y value column everythyme:
[image: faulty plot]

PS: I'm using R only to visualise my data so my focus of knowledge is on ggplot2. This code runs inside an R view node in KNIME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aes_string` like this:

```
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes_string(colnames(iris)[j], colnames(iris)[i], color = "Species"), shape=18, size=3.5) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

This also makes sure you don't have to use `labs()` anymore.

This gives

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Do you also happen to have an explanation why this works? The documentation hints that aes() isn't evaluated immediately while aes_string() is. Do I understand that correctly? :)

Comment: Usually, you use `ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Height))`. If you want to do it programmatically, like you do, instead of `Sepal.Width` you have a variable that contains a string, say `x <- "Sepal.Width"`. In order to be able to use that, you need `aes_string(x)`, since `aes(x)` would look for a column named `x`, which does not exist. Why your code does not work, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: It can't be that though, because the minimal change needed to get my code working is to replace "aes" with "aes_string". I still hand over the entire column with x = iris[,i] because the real data set has spaces in the column names (won't work otherwise, the "x =" is optional). I should probably reference columns by their name in the future though.

Comment: Yes, if you look at `plot_list[[2]]$layers[[1]]$mapping` after you ran either of the two versions, you can see that one has evaluated `x` and `y`, whereas the other has not, so it will at the final stage substitute `i` and `j`, which at that point are both 4, so "Petal.Width".